# To use Pandoc pipe data with AWK

Tags: sed, awk

Data

```
ID     | Size      | Blocks
-------|-----------|---------
206  |80760288   | 157744 
207  |80760288   | 157744
328  |241520288  | 471728
```

Wanted output by AWK

```
ID     |BlockSize | Size      | Blocks
-------|----------|-----------|---------
206  | 511.971  |80760288   | 157744 
207  | 511.971  |80760288   | 157744
328  | 511.991  |241520288  | 471728
```

where `blockSize` is Size/Blocks.

How can you do this conversion with AWK?

Comment: What do you want to do with data?

Comment: Are you asking how to add the extra column to your input data or how to then plot it in gnuplot? Those are two different questions.

Comment: Then why are you asking about gnuplot? I still don't understand. Please [edit] your question and just ask what you need. Do you want what you are calling "Wanted output" or do you want what you call "Data for Gnuplot"? I _think_ your question is how to convert the input into the "Data for Gnuplot" but, if so, I don't understand why you've added all the extra bits.

Comment: Thanks! One last question then. Are you _sure_ this is what you need? :) Do you really need the ASCII separator (`---|---` etc.)? That would seem to only complicate things for no reason. Why would you want it in the output?

Comment: @terdon Please, add your alternative output to the answer. It is Pandoc standard in pipe tables. I do not know if they bad or good. I am just testing them. I am also newbie in this area. Please, also add explanations why you think the ASCII separator complicates things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk -F'|' -vOFS="|" '{
    if(NR==1){print $1," Blocksize ",$2,$3}
    else if(NR==2){print $1,"-----------",$2,$3}
    else{printf "%-7s|%-11s|%-11s|%-11s\n",$1,$2/$3,$2,$3}
}' file
ID     | Blocksize | Size      | Blocks
-------|-----------|-----------|---------
206    |511.971    |80760288   | 157744    
207    |511.971    |80760288   | 157744    
328    |511.991    |241520288  | 471728
```

That, however, is made needlessly complex by the need to keep the columns aligned. Since I suspect you don't really need that, you might just want to use this instead:

```
$ sed 's/[-|]/ /g;/^ *$/d' file | 
   awk '{if(NR==1){print $1,"Blocksize",$2,$3}else{print $1,$2/$3,$2,$3}}'
ID Blocksize Size Blocks
206 511.971 80760288 157744
207 511.971 80760288 157744
328 511.991 241520288 471728
```

While this is slightly less human-friendly, it is perfect input for any program that expects space-delimited data.

Comment: For the first sed, you can also use `awk '!/(^\s*$|^-{2,})/' sandboxgp.data | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/|/ /g'` where you remove >=2 dashes with AWK and then finally do pipe removal by SED. The last AWK is great!

Comment: @Masi well, yes, but that is more complex and makes two calls to external programs. You could also do the whole thing in awk: `awk -F"|" '!/^-/{if(NR==1){print $1,"Blocksize",$2,$3}else{print $1,$2/$3,$2,$3}}' file`. I prefer using `sed` for this sort of thing though since I find its syntax simpler for small modifications like this.